# Disable legend charts.js when width < XXX px

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, chart.js

I'm facing an issue, when i open my website into a mobile format.

By Default my charts is like this 
[image: My Chart.JS]

And when i put into mobile my chart look like this

[image: Mobile Chart.JS]

So i want to know how disable the legend when my width is < 468px.

I cant use styles and media queries cause its a canvas.

My code HTML :

```
 <canvas  id="ca" width="300" height="200"></canvas>
```

Script :

```
    <script>
    var ctx = document.getElementById("ca");
    var clients = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
            labels: <?php echo json_encode($annee_s2mi) ?>,
            datasets: [
            {
                label: "Chiffre d'affaire S2MI",
                data: <?php echo json_encode($montant_s2mi) ?>,
                backgroundColor: "rgba(255,87,87,0.4)",
                hoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(255,87,87,1)",
            },
            {
            label: "Chiffre d'affaire JBM41",
                data: <?php echo json_encode($montant_jbm41) ?>,
                backgroundColor: "rgba(232,208,75,0.4)",
                hoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(232,208,75,1)",
            },
            {
            label: "Chiffre d'affaire ENTI",
                data: <?php echo json_encode($montant_enti) ?>,
                backgroundColor: "rgba(160,206,95,0.4)",
                hoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(160,206,95,1)",
            },
            {
            label: "Chiffre d'affaire APRIME",
                data: <?php echo json_encode($montant_aprime) ?>,
                backgroundColor: "rgba(152,0,42,0.4)",
                hoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(152,0,42,1)",
            },
            {
            label: "Chiffre d'affaire du Groupe",
                data: <?php echo json_encode($montant_groupe) ?>,
                backgroundColor: "rgba(41,39,56,0.4)",
                hoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(41,39,56,1)",
            }
            ]
        },
        options: {
            tooltips: {
                callbacks: {
                  label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
                    var datasetLabel = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].label || '';
                    return datasetLabel + ' : ' + tooltipItem.yLabel + ' €';
                  }
                }
            },
                scales: {
                    yAxes: [{
                      scaleLabel: {
                        display: true,
                        labelString: 'En Euro (€)'
                      }
                    }]
                },
        }
    });
</script>
```

Thanks for helping !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with something like this :

```
if ($(window).width() < 500) {
  $(".doughnut-legend").hide();
} else {
  $(".doughnut-legend").show();
}
$(window).resize(function(e) {
  if ($(this).width() < 500) {
    $(".doughnut-legend").hide();
  } else {
    $(".doughnut-legend").show();
  }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Tintin37/k568zvcr/

**EDIT**

You can generate the legend as Html, and play with the div generated.It's not perfect, I ll try to find a better way to hide the legend

http://jsfiddle.net/Tintin37/5eLtdzck/

**EDIT2**

Like that it looks good :

http://jsfiddle.net/Tintin37/b9w2r01m/

Comment: You give me a code for Chart.js v2 i'm on the v3, its maybe cause of this that i cant make your code working

Comment: If you can provide a jsfiddle It ll be easier for me to help you.